# Issue with Python ping sweep script

Tags: python, linux, bash, for-loop, ping

```
import subprocess 

nrange = "192.168.229."

for i in range(0, 254):
        address = nrange + str(i)
        res = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '3', address])
        if res == 0:
            print "ping to", address, "OK"
        elif res == 2:
            print "no response from", address
        else:
            print "ping to", address, "failed!"
```

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# ./pypsweep.py
^C./pysweep.py: line 3: nrange: command not found
./pysweep.py: line 5: syntax error unexpected toke `('
./pysweep.py: line 5: `for i in range (0, 254):'
root@kali:~/Desktop#
```

I am having an issue the above code. I am attempting to write a ping sweep script through Python to run in bash. I have tried several examples posted by other people around the interwebs but non seem to be functioning for me. This code is one that I wrote based off the simplest example I could find. I'm not sure if I am just simply overlooking an obvious error or what the issue could be. Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

This is being ran on VMware Workstation Pro on Kali Linux distro if that matters at all.

Comment: Never post pictures of code. Post the actual code...

Comment: I assume you mean `from subprocess import *` instead of `import subprocess *`. That's probably what causes your syntax error, because Python is trying (unsuccessfully) to multiply `subprocess` and `nrange`.

Comment: Also, your inner loop indentation is all messed up. That'll cause an `IndentationError` after you fix what @Aurora0001 suggested.

Comment: Okay I added the code to the post,

I have changed the syntax for import to 'from subprocess import *' as @Aurora0001 mentioned and adjusted the indentation like florin stated. Still getting the same syntax error at line 5 where the 'for loop' starts

Comment: `import subprocess *` should be `import subprocess` or `from subprocess import *` I'm guessing the prior since `subprocess.call([`

Comment: @MooingRawr I don't think there's any difference between `range (0, 254)` and `range(0, 254)`. PEP 8 probably recommends your suggestion though, but I don't think it's the cause of the syntax error.

Comment: I have updated the code with your suggestions in my OP. Still the same error with line 3 and 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not have a shebang line.  As a consequence, when this command is run:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# ./pypsweep.py
```

the shell attempts to interpret ./pypsweep.py as the default type: a shell script.  That is why you see the errors that you see.

There are two solutions.

1. Call python explicitly:

   root@kali:~/Desktop# python ./pypsweep.py
2. Add this line to the beginning of your script:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   ```

   If you python is not in /usr/bin, adjust the path appropriately.

Comment: Adding #!/usr/bin/python to the start of the file fixed this issue. Thank you very much!